# I want Excel to return a value based on a table of information

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Trying to automate a set of scoring for an older golf buddy. There are strokes added based on where their score lands in a chart.  I'm trying to write a formula that returns one of 5 values after searching 5 columns and return the appropriate value beneath the column that it falls into.

[image: See this table for a visual]

Ex.

- Player a shots 95.   In the chart of values of 71-130, 95 falls in the 5th row of the 1st column. The values in column 1 require -2 strokes.
- Player B shoots 94. In the chart, 94 is in the 4th row of the 5th column and requires +2 strokes.

The formula in Player A's line should return "-2" and the formula for Player B should return "2".

Is this too hard for Excel to deal with?

I've tried Vlookup and Xlookup, along with IFS but it doesn't like that the numbers are non-consecutive or referencing a cell (because the chart does change. Cell reference would be preferable).

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE inside INDEX:

```
=INDEX(A13:E13,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(A1:E12)/(A1:E12=G2),1))
```

This will return the column in which the number is found to the INDEX.  With the math inside the AGGREGATE we get errors on every return except where it matches.  The `7` tells the formula to ignore all errors and as such there is only one value that can be returned.

[image]

Comment: What dark magic is this :) So first you generate a matrix with column numbers `{ 1, 2, ..., 5; 1, 2, ..., 5; 1, 2, ..., 5; ... }` and then divide by a selection matrix (all zero except a 1 in the position of interest). This generates a matrix with mostly #DIV0 errors except one entry with the column number of interest. `AGGREGATE(15...` picks the smallest (and only) value in the matrix ignoring the divide by zero errors. Finally INDEX is used to return the answer from the last row using the derived column number as index. Very clever! Basically a reversed engineered 2D HLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the following analytical formula:

```
=MOD(G2,5)-2
```

MOD calculates the remainder after integer division, i.e. 75 mod 5 is zero (5  goes into 75 perfectly) but 79 mod 5 returns 4 (79 = 15*5 + 4). So MOD(x, 5) will always return a number between 0 and 4. We offset this with -2 to always return a number between -2 and 2 as per your requirements. If your table "shifts" by one, e.g. 74 should return -2, simply shift the value before the MOD e.g. `=MOD(G2+1,5)-2`

The MOD formula will work from 75 onward, but obviously fail with the discontinuity at 72 to 74. What is the reason for the discontinuity?

To address this we add an IF statement with a shift as above:

```
=IF(G2<75, MOD(G2-2,5)-2, MOD(G2,5)-2)
```